# How can I make the text *full* of a line (by a new command)?

Tags: xetex

What I want to realize is like the below codes:

```
\mbox{}I\hfill like\hfill the\hfill world\hfill because\hfill it\hfill is\hfill beautiful\mbox{}
```

so that I can get the first line instead of the second line in the picture.

[image]

But it is inconvenient because of too much \hfill. How can I create a new command for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this (on a paragraph of its own):

```
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth][s]{I like the world because it is beautiful}
```

*Explanation*: the second  optional argument is for the alignment inside the box. `s` is for `stretch`.

*Edit*: as suggested by @egreg, we can simplify typing with a macro, and add a code to avoid any  `bad box` messages. Demo:

```
\newcommand\linefillwith[1]{\par\noindent\makebox[\linewidth][s]{\spaceskip=\fontdimen2\font plus 1fil minus \fontdimen4\font #1}}
\lipsum[11]\medskip 
\linefillwith{\color{red}I like the world because it is beautiful}
```

[image]

Comment: Adding `\spaceskip=\fontdimen2\font plus 1fil minus \fontdimen4\font` inside the argument to `\makebox` will avoid underfull box messages. Defining a suitable command is better.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @egreg. I've added it to my answer (with due credits, of course!).